# What is causing the array out of bounds runtime error?

Tags: c++, arrays, bounds, breadth-first-search

This is a method of a class which is used to find the exit of a 3-dimensional maze represented as a 3-d array. The array itself contains strings of length 6 of either 1 or 0. A '1' in the string means that you are able to move in that direction. For example, if the string at the current array element is 100001, this means that you can move north and you can also move down a level. The bit string corresponds with the directions north east south west up down. This method is currently unfinished so I know it does not yet find a viable solution but the switch statement at the end causes an array out of bounds error at run time. I am picturing the 3-d array as a 3-d cube with the outtermost array representing the vertical axis, the middle array representing the z axis coming in and out of the page and the inner most array representing the horizontal x axis. When at a current cell in the maze, you look at each bit in the string. For each possible move, you add that move to the q. Once done looking at the string, you move in the direction that was first added to the queue and repeat. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
void maze::solve(int startlevel, int startrow, int startcol, int endlevel,   int endrow, int endcol)
{
position current, exit;
current.level = startlevel;
current.row = startrow;
current.col = startcol;

exit.level = endlevel;
exit.row = endrow;
exit.col = endcol;

q.push('0');
while (!q.empty())
{
    if (current == exit)
    {
        cout << "exit found" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (mazeGraph[current.level][current.row][current.col].at(0) == '1')
        q.push('n');
    if (mazeGraph[current.level][current.row][current.col].at(1) == '1')
        q.push('e');
    if (mazeGraph[current.level][current.row][current.col].at(2) == '1')
        q.push('s');
    if (mazeGraph[current.level][current.row][current.col].at(3) == '1')
        q.push('w');
    if (mazeGraph[current.level][current.row][current.col].at(4) == '1')
        q.push('u');
    if (mazeGraph[current.level][current.row][current.col].at(5) == '1')
        q.push('d');

    if (q.front() == '0')
        q.pop();

    switch (q.front())
    {
    case 'n':
        current.row -= 1;
    case 'e':
        current.col += 1;
    case 's':
        current.row += 1;
    case 'w':
        current.col -= 1;
    case 'u':
        current.level += 1;
    case 'd':
        current.level -= 1;

    }

}   
return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To debug, before accessing `mazeGraph[current.level][current.row][current.col]` you should check if `current.level` is in between `minLevel` and `maxLevel` similarly with `current.row` and `current.col` are all in bounds of mazeGraph. If they are not print a message with `current.level` and you will know why its throwing that error.

I am also assuming your mazeGraph is initialized to have that bounds satisfied with start and end levels etc.

PS: For better pathfinding between two nodes in a matrix, A* (A star) algorithm is found to be a better solution in many cases.

Comment: I am trying to do so using

 "if (current.level < 0 || current.level >= this.numlevels)
  {
   cout << "out of bounds" << endl;
  }"

but the compiler says that "this" requires a class type